# Can I change the default settings for SQL Server Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

Is there a way to change the default setting in SQL Server replication? Example when I create an new article I want to have the create Non-Cluster set to true all the time.

Answer (score 1):

there is no default server configuration setting to achive this task. Replication is article based and that can done after creating replication. 
you can add number of articles once by add dialog wizard and then enable property by "set properties of all table articles".

[image]

Make sure reinitialization of subscription is required after changing the property.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot change the default UI settings but you can create your publication and add articles via T-SQL script using [sp_addarticle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173857.aspx) and set the appropriate **@schema_option**.

Comment: You can also try this: in the Articles dialog, open the Articles drop-down list, then select Set Properties of all table articles, and go ahead from there.